# Remove Separator from Grouped UItableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm using an UITableView *Style* **Grouped** *Seperator* **NO**

When the table view loads I See a small distance between the cells.

[image]

and when scrolled it goes away

[image]

Need to get rid of that line. what is that I'm missing.

Comment: are you using simulator?

Comment: this is not the recommended fix, but you could set the background color of the table view or the separator to white

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich I faced this issue in all devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All,

Have solved this by setting Bottom Constraint of the view to -1, and unchecked Clip To Bounds for both UITableViewCell and its Content View.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will help you.

Write this in your viewDidLoad

```
 tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

And write this method for UITableView

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

      if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
          [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
      }

      if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
          [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
      }

      if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
          [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Parvendra Singh, it did not help me